# Instalar docker en maquina virtual Sistema operativo Linux

Tags: linux, docker, debian, virtualbox, kali-linux

Tengo un problema en la instalación de docker en kali , lo estoy intentando por el medio manual , no puedo solucionarlo me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, lecturas altamente recomendadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> aquí aprenderás el funcionamiento del sitio con respecto a preguntas y respuestas, de paso obtendrás tu primera medalla. Por otro lado, aquí tienes una recomendaciones para incrementar las chances de obtener respuesta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.